# When parsing html why do I need item.text sometimes and item.text_content() others

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

Still learning lxml.  I discovered that sometimes I cannot get to the text of an item from a tree using item.text.  If I use item.text_content() I am good to go.  I am not sure I see why yet.  Any hints would be appreciated

Okay I am not sure exactly how to provide an example without making you handle a file:

here is some code I wrote to try to figure out why I was not getting some text I expected:

```
theTree=html.fromstring(open(notmatched[0]).read()) 
text=[]
text_content=[]
notText=[]
hasText=[]
for each in theTree.iter():
    if each.text:
        text.append(each.text)
        hasText.append(each)   # list of elements that has text each.text is true
    text_content.append(each.text_content()) #the text for all elements 
    if each not in hasText:
        notText.append(each)
```

So after I run this I look at

```
>>> len(notText)
3612
>>> notText[40]
<Element b at 26ab650>
>>> notText[40].text_content()
'(I.R.S. Employer'
>>> notText[40].text
```

Comment: Providing some examples would help answering your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Accordng to [the docs](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#html-element-methods) the `text_content` method:

> Returns the text content of the element, including the text content of
>   its children, with no markup.

So for example,

```
import lxml.html as lh
data = """<a><b><c>blah</c></b></a>"""
doc = lh.fromstring(data)
print(doc)
# <Element a at b76eb83c>
```

`doc` is the `Element` `a`. The `a` tag has no text immediately following it (between the `<a>` and the `<b>`. So `doc.text` is `None`:

```
print(doc.text)
# None
```

but there is text after the `c` tag, so `doc.text_content()` is not `None`:

```
print(doc.text_content())
# blah
```

PS. There is a clear description of the meaning of the `text` attribute [here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text). Although it is part of the docs for `lxml.etree.Element`, I think the meaning of the `text` and `tail` attributes applies equally well to `lxml.html.Element` objects.

Comment: .text or .text_content() return text string, How I can get html source code instead of text string only?

Answer (score 5):

You maybe confusing different and incompatible interfaces that `lxml` implements -- the `lxml.etree` items have a `.text` attribute, while (for example) those from [lxml.html](http://codespeak.net/lxml/dev/lxmlhtml.html) implement the `text_content` method (and those from [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html), *also* included in `lxml`, have a `.string` attribute... *sometimes* [[only nodes with a single child which is a string...]]).

Yeah, it *is* inherently confusing that `lxml` chooses both to implement its own interfaces *and* emulate or include other libraries, but it can be convenient...;-).

Comment: I made some modifications I used the lxml.html interface