# How to get text from HTML element by using lxml.html

Tags: python, html, lxml, lxml.html

I've been trying to get a full text hosted inside a `<div>` element from the web page https://www.list-org.com/company/11665809. 
The element should contain a sub-string "Арбитраж".
And it does, because my code

```
for div in tree.xpath('.//div[contains(text(), "Арбитраж")]'):
    print(div)
```

returns response

```
Element div at 0x15480d93ac8
```

[image]

But when I'm trying to get the full text itself by using method `div.text`, it returns `None`
Which is a strange result, I think.
What should I do?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
As well as an advice about source to learn basics of HTML (not a savvy programmer guy) to avoid such an easy question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of these strange things that happens when xpath is handled by a host language and library. 
When you use the xpath expression

```
 .//div[contains(text(), "Арбитраж")]
```

the search is performed according to xpath rules, which considers the target text as contained within the target `div`. 
When you go on to the next line:

```
print(div.text)
```

you are using lxml.html, which apparently doesn't regard the target text as part of the `div` text, because it's preceded by the `<i>` tag. To get to it, with lxml.html, you have to use:

```
print(div.text_content())
```

or with xpath only:

```
print(tree.xpath('.//div[contains(text(), "Арбитраж")]/text()')[0])
```

It seems lxml.etree and beautifulsoup use different approaches. [See this interesting discussion here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517461/when-parsing-html-why-do-i-need-item-text-sometimes-and-item-text-content-othe)

Comment: **Thanks a lot, @Jack Fleeting.** In this case  `print(div.text_content())` returns an error `AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'text_content'`, but `print(tree.xpath('.//div[contains(text(), "Арбитраж")]/text()')[0])` works. I can't say that it works as I want it does, because it gives only `Арбитраж: ` which is not a full text of element, `Арбитраж (1 шт.):`. Anyway now I know reasons.